# Moving to another page after success in login xcode

Tags: ios, sql-server, modalviewcontroller

I am trying to move to a page after a successful message from my server for a basic login application. Currently when I get a successful log it moves to a black screen like its looking a view controller thats not there. However there is a view controller accioated with the class i am trying to go to. Here is my code so far

```
    if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Yes there was a match");
        WelcomeScreenViewController *newview =[[WelcomeScreenViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:newview animated:YES completion:nil];
        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congrats" message:@"You are authorized"
                                                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];


        [alertsuccess show];
       `}
```

Why isn't after i successfully log in it taking me to the welcome screen? Do I need to make the welcome the rootcontroller and then push the log-in screen. Why can't I programmatically move to the view controller with an if statement?

`- (IBAction)loginbuttonpressed:(id)sender {

```
//Trim white space off username/password
NSString *rawEmail = [_UIEmailTextField text];
NSString *rawPass = [_UIPasswordTextField text];
NSString *trimmedEmail = [rawEmail stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSString *trimmedPass = [rawPass stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

//Check if text field is empty
if([_UIEmailTextField.text length] > 0 && [_UIPasswordTextField.text length] > 0)
{
    NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userName=%@&userPassword=%@",trimmedEmail, trimmedPass];
    NSString *hostStr = @"http://server name?";
    hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
    NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];
    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Yes there was a match");
        WelcomeScreenViewController *newview =[[WelcomeScreenViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:newview animated:YES completion:nil];
        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congrats" message:@"You are authorized"
                                                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];`


    So all of this is run when you hit a log in button. I had it being a seque when you click log in but then if the log in fails it still logs in.
```

Comment: You need to init the view xib or from a segue.

Comment: I have a login button that activated this code? Problem is then it always moves to the welcome screen even if the log in is suppose to fail.

Comment: You need to be firing an IBAction that does the check for Yes or No. Are you using a segue? Place more details about your usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When testing for a value prior to a segue you should impliment a segue from the viewController rather than from the UIButton. You then use performSegueWithIdentifier to execute the segue you added to the controller. Then in your prepareForSegue you can test for different segues and pass things to the destinationViewController.

[Perform Segue programmatically and pass parameters to the destination view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248798/perform-segue-programmatically-and-pass-parameters-to-the-destination-view)

Comment: So would that replace the line `WelcomeScreenViewController *newview =[[WelcomeScreenViewController alloc] init];`

Comment: Yes. But if you are saying the view changes regardless then it sounds like you are using a segue as well. You can set the bundle to nil but the nib name needs to be set.

Comment: I am using a seque. Is there a way to cancel a seque way even if the button is pressed if some other action isn't met?

Comment: Yes, in the case of a segue, remove the segue from the button and create one from the UIViewController. Then in your IBAction run [self performSegueWithIdentifier@""]; Now you need to implement the prepareForSegue method if you are wanting to pass anything to the new view.

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248798/perform-segue-programmatically-and-pass-parameters-to-the-destination-view

Comment: MarkM you are truly a hero!

Comment: Your welcome! Mark the question answered if you are satisfied with the answer. Enjoy and good luck!