# Passing cell title to detail view using storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitableview, segue

I'm trying to pass the selected cell title to deatil view controller using storyboards but it's not as easy becuse of the cell selection.

I have no clue how to determine which one was selected at the moment and pass it's title to the deatil views property.

I guess I have to use `prepareForSegue:sender` first (this is where I get everything) and call  `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` inside `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, right?

Here are my samples:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"projectDetailsSegue"]) {
        AlbumViewController *destinationView = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedRowIndex];
        destinationView.projectTitle = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"projectDetailsSegue" sender:self];
}
```

And when I log projectTitle in detail view controller it shows `(null)`.

Here is my question - How can I do this and pass this title to another view controller to use it?

Comment: Please look at this link : http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/ hope it will help you.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Shame I havent't found it earlier! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248798/perform-segue-programmatically-and-pass-parameters-to-the-destination-view). And here is my proper `prepareForSegue:sender:` method body:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"projectDetailsSegue"]) {
        AlbumViewController *destinationView = [segue destinationViewController];
        UITableViewCell *selectedCell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;
        destinationView.projectTitle = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
    }
}
```