# Swift 2 - prepareForSegue nil Value

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to send a link over another view when a select a row in `UITableView`.
When I select the row I can see the link is printed however, the value does not get to the function `prepareForSegue`. 
It seems like the `prepareForSegue` function is called before the selection row in `UITableView`.

```
var videouserPath = ""

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        videouserPath =  self.arrayUserVideo[indexPath.row][4]
        print("tableview: ----\(videouserPath)")
    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        print("segue: ----\(videouserPath)")
        if segue.identifier == "toUserVideo"

        {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? GetVideo_ViewController{

                destinationVC.videoToDisplay = videouserPath
            }
        }
    }
```

I got in debug:

> segue: ----
>
> tableview: ----https://example.com/resources/1361929513_02-02-2016_125830.mov

Why is the segue function called before selection?

Comment: Maybe by setting the segue in the Storyboard from your `UIViewController` rather from the `UITableViewCell` to `GetVideo_ViewController`?

Answer (score 1):

When linking `UIStoryboardSegue` to `UITableViewCell` from the storyboard, the messaging is in the order `prepareForSegue`, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

## Automatic Method

**Bypass `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` altogether**.

For general purpose and single selection cells, you do not need to implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Let the segue associated with `UITAbleViewCell` do the work, and handle selection like so:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detailSegueIdentifier" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            print(indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

## Manual Method

If you absolutely need to do extra work before the segue, do not associate it to the `UITableViewCell` but to the `UITableViewController`. You will then need to trigger it programmatically. Inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248798/perform-segue-programmatically-and-pass-parameters-to-the-destination-view).
In **IB**, assign the segue to table view controller, give it an identifier (say `detailSegueIdentifier`), and invoke it like so.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
                            didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("didSelectRowAtIndexPath")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detailSegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
    }
```

---

**Passing parameters to the segue:**

Invoking `performSegueWithIdentifier` will also give you a chance to explicitly pass parameters, not second-guess `indexPathForSelectedRow`, and not rely on a global(*).

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
                        didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("didSelectRowAtIndexPath")
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detailSegueIdentifier", sender: indexPath)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detailSegueIdentifier" {
        if let indexPath = sender as? NSIndexPath {
            let name = db[indexPath.row].key
            if let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController {
                controller.name = name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

(*) *Don't ever rely on globals if you can help it*.