# Accessing text from a tag view

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a search tags view for my app. It allows users to add search tags to make searching easier. The search tag view is all done. But I'm having problems accessing the text from the tags and compiling them together to make one large string. Can someone help me. Here is the code. I took the repo project rrtagcontroller from github and customized it. All i want to do is take the text from all the tags and put them in one big string so that I can pass the data to the next view controller.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let tag = ["Macbookpro13inch"]

    RRTagController.displayTagControllerAsAChild(self, frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 161.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 161), tagsString: tag, blockFinish: { (selectedTags, unSelectedTags) -> () in
    }) { () -> () in
    }

}

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination
    vc.transitioningDelegate = transition
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom

    if (segue.identifier == "ToHomeRoomDetailsViewController"){
        var destinationVC:HomeRoomDetailsViewController = segue.destination as! HomeRoomDetailsViewController


        destinationVC.HomeDescriptiontext = tagString

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the github page of RRTagController, the two callback blocks will either provide a list of selected and unselected tags or nothing if user cancels. So according to your code, you can access the tags in the blocks as follows:

```
RRTagController.displayTagControllerAsAChild(self, frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 161.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 161), tagsString: tag, blockFinish: { (selectedTags, unSelectedTags) -> () in

    //map the selectedTags into an array of strings
    let selectedTagsAsStrings = selectedTags.map { $0.textContent }

    //join the strings into one comma-separated string
    let tagString = selectedTagsAsStrings.joinWithSeparator(",")

    //do everything else with tagString
    //for e.g., store it locally
    self.tagString = tagString

}) { () -> () in
    //user did not select any tag, remember to handle this as well
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to pass data to the next view controller. How do I pass selectedtagsasstrings to the next viewcontroller

Comment: It depends. If you are using storyboards, you can store the selected tags as an instance var, perform the segue programmatically (`performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`), set the selected tags within `func prepare(for: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
 `. Alternatively, you can just programmatically init the next view controller, set the selected tags on the view controller and show the next view controller

See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13980519/1594442

Comment: i know how to pass data. but what would the string I'm passing be. how would i declare that. How would I call over all of the selectedtagsasstrings

Comment: You can declare a variable of type [String] on the next view controller class. Then after initializing the next view controller, set it to `selectedTagsAsStrings`

Comment: To call over that data, use a for in loop

Comment: Hong Wei, when I try to access tag string in the (func prepare(for: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)), I get a "use of unresolved identifier 'tag string') error when I try to declare it to this (destinationVC.HomeDescriptiontext = tagString)

Comment: what should i do for this

Comment: what is your suggestion

Comment: Hong Wei, can you make an edit to your code and show me

Comment: You need to store it into an instance variable in the `blockFinish`.

Comment: can you show me how that would look. Im going to edit my code to show you what I'm talking about. And then can you make a re-edit to show me what your talking about

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: is this what your talking about

Comment: self.tagString = tagString

Comment: Yes, because after blockFinish executes, the value would be lost, so you need an instance variable to hold it

Comment: can you look at my edit to show me where tapstring would go in the override prepare func

Comment: Your code looks alright to me. You just need to declare an instance variable on this class. `var tagString: String?` it is declared optional as user may or may not have selected any tags

Comment: Hey Hong Wei, I was wondering if you could help me with something else