# Passing variable through classes

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to pass a variable through a few different classes to use in core data (one to many relationships).

To give some context of what is happening. I have a tableViewController (jobs), when a user clicks on one of the cells it takes them to a tabBarController with 4 viewControllers. Then on the first viewController is a tableView, if the user clicks on a specific cell it takes them to another tabBarController. I am trying to pass the variable

> var job: Job?

from the top level to the final tabBarController but it seems to be getting lost when trying to pass the variable from the first TabBarcontroller to the second tabBarController. I am struggling to see what is wrong to not pass the variable through the ViewControllers.

Here each of the ViewControllers variables and how I am passing them:

JobViewController:

```
var jobs = [Job]()

// CELL DID SELECT ROW
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let jobTab = jobTabController()
        jobTab.job = jobs[indexPath.row]
        show(jobTab, sender: self)
    }
```

This is the first tabBarController - **jobTabController:**

```
var job: Job?
```

This is the first ViewController that is attached to jobTabController - **jobInfo:**

```
// OBSERVE JOB
var job: Job? {
    let tabBarController = self.tabBarController as! jobTabController
    return tabBarController.job
}

    // CELL DID SELECT ROW
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == 1 {
            if indexPath.row == 1 {
                let camLens = cameraLensesTabController()
                camLens.job = self.job
                show(camLens, sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
```

NOTE: This is where the variable seems to get lost - between jobInfo & cameraLensesTabController - name: **cameraLensesTabController**

```
var job: Job?
```

Then this is my viewController that is attached to cameraLensesTabController - **cameraController:**

```
var job: Job?

@IBAction func HandleAddCamera(sender : UIButton) {
        let newCamera = newCameraController()
        newCamera.job = self.job
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: newCamera)
        present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

On the cameraController I have an add button that takes you to another ViewController named **newCameraController** where you can add items to a tableView on cameraController:

```
var job: Job?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `jobInfo` controller, you access `var job` via `tabBarController.job`. But in the `cameraLensesTabController` you have a `var Job?` that is apparently initialised to `nil`, like in the `cameraController`.
Did you expect that these two controllers can access the original value of `tabBarController.job`? Apparently, you did never forward it to them.

EDIT:

When a viewController performs a segue (i.e. switches to) to another one, it calls first `prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`or its Swift equivalence. In this function, you can access the destination viewController and set properties there, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7865100/1987726.

EDIT 2:

The `prepareForSegue:sender:` method is called in any case. Please lookup [Perform Segue programmatically and pass parameters to the destination view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248798/perform-segue-programmatically-and-pass-parameters-to-the-destination-view).

Comment: Yes, I want to access the original value from `JobViewController`. How do I forward it to cameraLensesTabController instead of it being initialised to nil?

Comment: Is this the same when doing it programmatically? I am trying to forward the job in the function `cellDidSelectRow` in the VC called `jobTabController`.